# save and load the content to which the user zoomed uiscrollview ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, zooming

[image]
Its been a pain in the ass to get a working solution for this problem. On a view i have around five scroll views with maximum zoom upto 5 . What i want is if a user has zoomed into a particular region of image , and then comes back , scroll view sets the image wherever it was left . I have tried using content Offset and content Inset property but that does'nt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to save somewhere both the value of the scroll view's `contentOffset` property *and* `zoomScale`.

When you want to move your scrollview back to that position you just do

```
[myScrollView setZoomScale:lastZoomScale];
[myScrollView setContentOffset:lastContentOffset];
```

Comment: i was setting the content offset first and then setting the zoom scale . silly mistake.